# MySQL locks entire table instead row when Select For Update

Tags: php, mysql, concurrency, transactions, innodb

I have a table name that keys. There are many keys in that table. And i have a multiple daemon process that working on php  at same time.

I want that when a process selects a key, another process can't select same key for that.

I try this scenario with this code:

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=UTF-8', 'root', '123456');

try {
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db->exec("SET autocommit=0;");

    $db->beginTransaction();

    $stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM keys WHERE resetTime IS NULL OR resetTime > ' . time() . ' LIMIT 0,1 FOR UPDATE");
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    echo("rows: " . print_r($rows,true));
    //sleep(20);

    /*
    update command will be here for selected row
    */

    $db->commit();
} catch(PDOException $ex) {
        //Something went wrong rollback!
        $db->rollBack();
        echo $ex->getMessage();
}
?>
```

In this scenario, I use 2 terminal window with php command. in the first command, i uncomment the sleep row because wait of transaction.

in the second window, comment the sleep line and execute the same code. but, it waits the first process to select another row. (The keys table has many rows that resetTime is null)

How can i achieve this operation that each process select a single key (and after update that selected key for own)

Comment: Why have you started a transaction, is this absolutely necessary here? One of the features of a transaction is that data remains in the same state throughout the transaction, so I would expect to see locking like this.

Comment: i use transaction for update after select. (there will be update query for selected wor that. i will execute a query for update that row which process selected as it)